# how create new route in open cart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3, opencart-3

How create a new route/page in open cart in version 2.3.0.2?

I need create a page with fixed content....

I create a controller and view, but, not working...

any tutorial or example for me to redo again?

Controller

```
<?php
class ControllerProductSimulator extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {

    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
    $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
    $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/simulator', $data));

}


}
?>
```

View

```
<?php echo $header; 
$theme_options = $registry->get('theme_options');
$config = $registry->get('config');
$page_direction = $theme_options->get( 'page_direction' );
$background_status = false;
$product_page = true;
$cart_info = $theme_options->getCart();
include('catalog/view/theme/'.$config->get($config->get('config_theme') . '_directory').'/template/new_elements/wrapper_top.tpl'); ?>
<style>

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.slider {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.slider li {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.slider img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;


} 
.slider input {
    display: none;
}

.slider label {

    bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 100;

    border: 3px solid white;
}

.slider li:nth-child(1) label {
    background: url('catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $config->get($config->get('config_theme') . '_directory'); ?>/simulator/images/3.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.slider li:nth-child(2) label {
    background: url('catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $config->get($config->get('config_theme') . '_directory'); ?>/simulator/images/2.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left: 125px;
}

.slider li:nth-child(3) label {
    background: url('catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $config->get($config->get('config_theme') . '_directory'); ?>/simulator/images/268-1.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left: 250px;
}

.slider img {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slider li input:checked ~ img {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10;
} 


</style>


    <ul class="slider"   style="background-image: url('catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $config->get($config->get('config_theme') . '_directory'); ?>/simulator/default.jpg');">

        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="slide" checked>
            <label for="slide1" ></label>
            <img src="http://db65e810-95dd-0132-d8f0-705681baa5c1.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/duratex/admin/upload/ambiente_piso/270.png" />                
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="slide">
            <label for="slide2"></label>
            <img src="http://db65e810-95dd-0132-d8f0-705681baa5c1.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/duratex/admin/upload/ambiente_piso/266.png" />                
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="slide">
            <label for="slide3"></label>
            <img src="http://db65e810-95dd-0132-d8f0-705681baa5c1.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/duratex/admin/upload/ambiente_piso/268.png" />                
        </li>
    </ul>

<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'?

Comment: 404 - not found routeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: Please update your question with that information then. 'its not working' can mean anything...